# Rooted my LG G Flex 2, but no root, and no supersu?

Tags: rooting, lg

So today i decided to root my Lg G Flex 2 which runs on 5.1.1. Using the pc method everything went fine with no errors, but when phone booted up i have no superuser, and root checker basic said no root along with some other root checking apps. So i then tried rooting with the APK method (KingRoot, and some other apks aswell), but it said root failed. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated! Also if it matters.. I bought the phone unlocked off amazon.
I will post specs below

Specs:

Lolipop: 5.1.1
Kernel: 3.10.49
Build: LMY47S
Software Version: V15c- TWN-XX
Model Number: LG-H959
Hardware Version: Rev.1.0

Comment: "the PC method" and this method would be? Please don't use "one click root" apps, you'll only get malware.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Kingroot"I have a LG tribute 2 and it rooted my phone with Kingroot from play store.Try unistalleing it,then reboot and install again.then download a root verifier and it will tell you if your phone is rooted......GOODLUCK!